# llamar procedimientos almacenados en codeigniter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando un pequeño software en codeigniter enlazado a una base de datos sql server.

Si realizo consultas normales (SELECT * FROM tabla), me funciona bien, pero cuando intento llamar un procedimiento almacenado no me funciona.Alguien ha realizado este tipo de ejercicios

Gracias!!!

Comment: cual es el SP? que error te arroja? edita y mejora tu pregunta con esa info

Answer (score -1):

Los procedimientos almacenados se llaman de esta manera dentro del SQL Server

```
EXEC(NOMBRE_PROCEDIMIENTO)
```